# One select_tag and multiple button_to submit buttons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have one select_tag and multiple button_to buttons on the same page. I'm looking to use the parameters from the select_tag for several of the buttons, is there a non-form way to do this?

The reason I don't want to use a form is two fold:
1. the number of buttons is dynamic
2. the positioning of the buttons do not follow the form structure (object at the top and submit at the bottom)

-here is one of the create methods that are linked to one of the buttons

```
def create
  params[:options].each do |x|
    @connector = Connector.find_or_create_by_options_id_and_follow_id(x.id, current_user.follow(@product).id)
    @connector.save
  end
end
```

I checked and this params[:options] is always nil no matter what is selected by me when I test

```
<%= select_tag :options, options_for_select(@current_user_options.map {|p| [p.name, p.id] }), {:multiple => true} %>
```

Comment: How did you submit the data without enclosing it in a form? Did u use javascript ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

button_to method actually creates a form which has a submit button, with the form action being the url which you had mentioned in button_to. So when you hit the submit button, obviously the options param will be nil, since the button_to form has no data in it

You can use a form itself, and form does not mandate, having an object at the top and submit button below. Submit button just submits the form irrespective of its position in the form

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you actually need a second field in your form that's a select field or radio buttons to choose your action. Then you have one button that submits the form, and in your controller you can then parse that new action field and decide where to redirect the user.